# "form data" does not show in the drop down menu for inbox entry in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I logged into my Dosusign web console. Looking at the inbox, there is a drop down menu when I position the mouse cursor at the right to each line of mail header. For certain mail items, the "Form Data" menu entry is missing. Can I know how to enable "Form Data" for each of the mail that I receive?

I have attached two pictures for you to compare. The second menu entry should be "Form Data".

(picture in URL to show two different menus)
http://1drv.ms/1Wz6B0L

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Form Data will only be available if you are the Sender of the envelope. Your Inbox is a collection of all documents sent to you to sign (whether you are the sender or not) so the discrepancy between some allowing it and some not is expected.

If you use the Sent Items folder all of the envelopes will have the Form Data option.